# jquery click bind not working when I use this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to make a section that folds up when the title is clicked on. It works if I use the following but obviously folds all sections up instead of just the clicked on:

```
$(".foldUpSection").find(".header").click(function()
{
    $(".foldUpSection").find(".foldMeUp").slideToggle();
});
```

I switched it to

```
$(".foldUpSection").find(".header").click(function()
{
    $(this).find(".foldMeUp").slideToggle();
});
```

but this does nothing. Am I missing something to why it is not passing the this on click?

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="foldUpSection">
    <span class="header">Unprocessed EDIs</span>
    <div id="unprocessedEdi" class="foldMeUp">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that context `this` refers to `$(".foldUpSection").find(".header")`

the `find()` function looks for descendants of a selector and `$(".foldUpSection").find(".header")` has no descendants with a class of `foldMeUp`.

Comment: This is not this, easy. That was not this either.

Comment: Ah! Excellent answer! Now I understand my issue, I was at the same level as the object I was looking for, not over it! That makes sense, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Using $(this) and .find() made you target the wrong element.

Use `.next()` or `.siblings()`, `find()` searches for children, foldmeup is a sibling

```
   $(this).siblings(".foldMeUp").slideToggle();
```

or

```
 $(this).next(".foldMeUp").slideToggle();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4vTBu/)

[**Documentation for .find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Ah sweet, any reason why find doesn't work in a passed DOM object?

Comment: it would works if you use find from .foldUpSection because .foldMeUp is a child of that element. .find() is a lot like .children()

Answer (score 1):

If the DOM structure is not set in stone (so that you might have other elements between `.header` & `.foldMeUp`, use this:

```
$(".foldUpSection").find(".header").click(function()
{
    $(this).closest(".foldUpSection").find(".foldMeUp").slideToggle();
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jEgK4/